# use :only helper in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a project where user can download files. Now, i want another page for show all users. so, i add a method `all_users` in my addfiles_controller. I have also a view page `all_users.html.erb` for that. But The ploblem is with the routes.rb file . Here I want to ensure user can only use `:index, :new, :create, :destroy, :all_users` paths.
How can i set this :only helper in my routes.rb file, like

```
resources :addfiles, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy, :all_users]
```

My routes.rb file::

```
  resources :addfiles do
    collection  do
      get 'all_users'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't write `all_users` to `only`, because `only/except` related just to standard actions `index, show, new, edit, create, update, destroy` which `resources` define by default

```
  resources :addfiles, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy] do
    collection  do
      get 'all_users'
    end
  end
```